# Apache redirect with REMOTE_USER variable not working

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REMOTE_USER} "=username"
RewriteRule ^/sourcepath$ $1/destpath [L,R=302,QSD]


<IfModule mod_auth_basic.c>
  <LocationMatch "^/sourcepath(.html|/.*)">
    Header unset Cache-Control
    RequestHeader unset Authorization
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "XYZ"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile "/location of auth file"
    Require valid-user
  </LocationMatch>
</IfModule>
```

the authentication works but it is not redirecting to the destination url

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
RewriteRule ^/sourcepath$ $1/destpath
```

You haven't used any parentheses, so `$1` refers to nothing. Did you mean `$0` which refers to the entire match, i.e. change `/sourcepath` to `/sourcepath/destpath`?